# En Angular, cual es la diferencia entre trabajar con objetos y trabajar con formularios?

Tags: angular, typescript, formularios, spring-boot

```
// Clase con objeto Medico
export class MedicoComponent implements OnInit {

  // Modelo medico
  medico: Medico;

  constructor()...
  ngOnInit()...

  getData() {
    this.medico = new Medico();
    this.medico.idMedico = this.data.idMedico;
    this.medico.nombres = this.data.nombres;
  }

// Clase con FormGroup
export class PacienteComponent implements OnInit {

form: FormGroup;

  getForm() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'id' : this.form.value.id,
      'nombres' : this.form.value.nombres,
    });
  }
```

Trabajando de las dos maneras obtienes el mismo resultado, pero cual es la diferencia? Siempre trabajamos con objetos si vamos a consumir servicios con Spring o con algún otro Backend, pero si trabajamos con formularios (FormGroup) también obtenemos la data y de igual manera la mostramos. Cual es la diferencia de estos dos enfoques?

Comment: Hola. Para mostrar los datos no se ocupan formularios. Si quieres que el usuario complete datos puedes usar formularios reactive o con directivas ngModel. ¿Cual es tu caso de uso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El factor que diferencia los Formularios de los objetos es simplemente la facilidad con la que puede validar y manjar la información.
Por ejemplo en los objetos para validar que un objeto contiene todos los datos o que una propiedad del objeto contiene solo números deberíamos crear funciones especificas para validar cada propiedad del objeto y así asegurarnos de que el objeto esta bien construido con todos sus datos correctos.

Esto se simplifica con un formulario, angular te da todas las opciones de validación que requieras incluso dejando agregar validaciones custom hechas por ti mismo atraves de regex.
Asi con una simple propiedad del formulario como es `this.form.status` podemos saber si el formulario esta bien rellenado ya que te devolvera 'VALID'  unicamente si el formulario a pasado las validaciones requeridas en cada campo.

Asi mismo puedes agregar validaciones a cada campo siendo cada uno una validacion especifica:

```
 getForm() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'id' : [this.form.value.id, Validators.required], (Hace que este campo sea obligatorio)
      'nombres' :  [this.form.value.nombres, Validators.minLength(6)] (Comprueba que el campo tenga como minimo 6 caracteres para ser valido)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me quedo resuelta la duda que tenía!